# send & receive data over a socket python3

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

I am attempting to send data after having prompted to enter text from keyboard input. The code seems to work, but the prompt does not appear. Can anybody suggest why?

Code to send is:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
  import socket
  class LogSocket:
    def __init__(self, socket):
      self.socket = socket

    def send(self, data):
      print( "Sending {0} to {1}".format(data, self.socket.getpeername()[0]) )
      self.socket.send(data)

    def close(self):
      self.socket.close()

  def respond(client):
    response = input("Enter a value: ")
    client.send(bytes(response, 'utf8'))
    client.close()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(('localhost',2401))
    server.listen(1)
    try:
      while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        respond(LogSocket(client))
    finally:
      server.close()
```

Code to receive is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 2401))
print("Received: {0}".format(client.recv(1024)))
client.close()
```

The behaviour is a bit strange. When I enter "Hello World" in the sending terminal and then enter, when I switch over to the receiving terminal and run the receiving script, there is no output. When I again enter "Hello World" and hit enter in the sender, I then rerun the receiving script and "Hello World" appears, but with the prompt from input!

Sender output:

```
Hello World
Enter a value: Sending b'' to 127.0.0.1
Hello World
Enter a value: Sending b'Hello World' to 127.0.0.1
```

Receiver output:

```
$ ./receive_data_socket1.py 
Received: b''
$ ./receive_data_socket1.py 
Received: b'Hello World'
```

Could anybody with experience in dealing with sockets in Python3 explain the behaviour? I am aware that the behaviour has changed in 3.5, which is what I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the server, it blocks inside the `server.accept()` call until a client is connected. i.e. until a client is connected, it will not execute the next line of code. It is only in the next line, the `respond(...)` function, that triggers the input prompt.

Try this

1. Start the server in one tab
2. Start the client in another tab
3. Go back to the server - you should see a prompt now

You're other option is to run the input prompt before `accept`, and store that in a variable. Then call `respond` with that variable - here's a snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
class LogSocket:
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket

    def send(self, data):
        print( "Sending {0} to {1}".format(data, self.socket.getpeername()[0]) )
        self.socket.send(data)

    def close(self):
        self.socket.close()

def respond(client, response):
    client.send(bytes(response, 'utf8'))
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(('localhost',2401))
    server.listen(1)
    try:
        while True:
            response = input("Enter a value: ")
            client, addr = server.accept()
            respond(LogSocket(client), response)
    finally:
        server.close()
```